# How to modify Python dictionary value and create the list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, append

I want to modify dictionary and to create a list that contains dictionaries with the modified values. I tried:

```
mylist = []
mydict = {"one": 10, "two": 20, "three": 30}
for i in [111, 222, 333]:
   mydict["two"] = i
   mylist.append(mydict)
```

mylist returns:

```
[{'three': 30, 'two': 333, 'one': 10}, {'three': 30, 'two': 333, 'one': 10},  {'three': 30, 'two': 333, 'one': 10}]
```

I expect to get:

```
[{'three': 30, 'two': 111, 'one': 10}, {'three': 30, 'two': 222, 'one': 10},  {'three': 30, 'two': 333, 'one': 10}]
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you are just creating multiple references to same object (your dictionary) and by assigning the throwaway variable `i` to your keys which  holds 333 at the last iteration and assign it to the `two` key, all of your dictionary names will point to same object with item `('two', 333)`.

You can use a dict comprehension for getting ride of this problem:

```
>>> mylist = [{"one": 10, "two": i, "three": 30} for i in [111, 222, 333]]
>>> mylist
[{'three': 30, 'two': 111, 'one': 10}, {'three': 30, 'two': 222, 'one': 10}, {'three': 30, 'two': 333, 'one': 10}]
```

Or you can create a copy of your initial object in each iteration in order to create a new object rather than just copying the references.

```
>>> from copy import copy
>>> mylist = []
>>> mydict = {"one": 10, "two": 20, "three": 30}
>>> for i in [111, 222, 333]:
...    mydict["two"] = i
...    mylist.append(copy(mydict))
... 
>>> mylist
[{'one': 10, 'three': 30, 'two': 111}, {'one': 10, 'three': 30, 'two': 222}, {'one': 10, 'three': 30, 'two': 333}]
```

And if you have multiple keys that you want to modify, as a more pythonic approach you can do:

```
>>> for i, j in zip(my_keys, my_new_values):
...    mydict[i] = j
...    mylist.append(copy(mydict))
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick response. It's works. Additional question, If I want to modify 2 and more values very long dictionary . Do you have a robust and elegant solution?